# Binding ListBoxItem with MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I am new with mvvm and wpf. I faced an issue for display a value in a ListBox. The number of machine showing in the Listbox are ok. I don't know how to name the Text in x:ResultMachDataTemplate that

Here my Code:

Page:

```
<Page.Resources>
 <ResourceDictionary Source="/Resources/ResourcePageCuttingData.xaml"/>
</Page.Resources>
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Machine}" Style="{StaticResource styleLocMach}" Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="1" Margin="20,0" />
```

ResourceDictionary:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:Project.CuttingSpeed">

<DataTemplate x:Key="ResultMachDataTemplate" DataType="vm:CuttingSpeed_ViewModel" >
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Machine}"
                   FontSize="20"
                   HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                   Foreground="White"
               ></TextBlock>
</DataTemplate>
<Style x:Key="styleMach" TargetType="{x:Type ListBox}">
    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True"></Setter>
    <Setter Property="ItemContainerStyle" Value="{DynamicResource ResourceKey=styleLocMachItem}"></Setter>
    <Setter Property="ItemTemplate" Value="{StaticResource ResourceKey=ResultMachDataTemplate}"></Setter>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListBox}">
                <Border BorderBrush="#5A5A5A" BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="4">
                    <ScrollViewer Margin="1">
                        <ItemsPresenter Margin="1"></ItemsPresenter>
                    </ScrollViewer>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

ViewModel:

```
namespace Project.CuttingSpeed
{
class CuttingSpeed_ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    Database db;

    public CuttingSpeed_ViewModel()
    {
        db = new Database();
        var CuttingSpeedInfos = db.gettoolsofmach();
        Machine = (from c in CuttingSpeedInfos
                 select c.Mach).Distinct().ToList();
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected internal void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyname)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyname));
    }

    private IEnumerable<string> _Machine;

    public IEnumerable<string> Machine
    {
        get { return _Machine; }
        set { _Machine = value; OnPropertyChanged("Machine"); }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: `Text="{Binding}"` instead of `Text="{Binding Machine}"`?

Comment: I thought I tried it before :/. It works like you said. ty very much

Comment: No worries, WPF / MVVM has a steep learning curve, it will take a little time to get used to it. Just try to understand what your `DataContext` is for any xaml element you are using. Then it's not a matter of trying but you will know that an `ItemsSource` as `IEnumerable<string>` results in an item `DataContext` of type `string` and you won't try to bind `string.Machine` anymore :)

Comment: 3 small remarks : use an observablecollection if machines are changing; don't put the data access layer (db) in your view model; when you do _Machine = value; test before if( _Machine != value )